# React JS - input onChange event not setting phone number as valid until 1 extra character typed

Tags: reactjs, validation, input, onchange

I am using the validator package in a React application (https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) to handle different validation examples. One I am struggling with is validator.isMobilePhone().

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import validator from 'validator'

export default function Login() {

let [phone, setPhone] = useState("")
let [valid, isValid] = useState("")

const setPhoneNum = (event) => {
    setPhone(event.target.value)
    isValid(validatePhoneNumber(event.target.value))
}

const validatePhoneNumber = (event) => {
    let isValidPhoneNumber = validator.isMobilePhone(phone, "en-US")
    return (isValidPhoneNumber)
}

return (
    <>
    ...
    <input
      type="tel"
      className="w-full input-primary pl-8 focus:outline-none"
      onChange={setPhoneNum}
      value={phone}
      placeholder="123 456 7890"
    />
    ...
    <>
)
}

Login.layout = Auth
```

This does not return true until an extra number is typed which has to do with onChange event not setting the value of phone until a change in the input happens. I think what I need is to set the value of phone on keyDown but just cannot figure it out

15308675309 - isValidPhoneNumber - false

153086753091 - isValidPhoneNumber - true

Comment: Did you try it with `onKeyUp` event?

Comment: onKeyUp/onKeyDown event does not change the value of the input which is phone. Maybe something to do with event.target.value in setPhone()

onKeyUp={setPhoneNum} for example does not change the state of phone

Comment: Check this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-tess-qiw7r7?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Change `onChange` to `onInput`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here, you are passing `event` as arg and not used in the function.

```
const validatePhoneNumber = (event) => {
    let isValidPhoneNumber = validator.isMobilePhone(phone, "en-US")
    return (isValidPhoneNumber)
}
```

Since, you are passing the value

```
const validatePhoneNumber = (value) => {
    let isValidPhoneNumber = validator.isMobilePhone(value, "en-US")
    return (isValidPhoneNumber)
}
```

```js
const Login = () => {
  let [phone, setPhone] = React.useState("");
  let [valid, isValid] = React.useState("");

  const setPhoneNum = (event) => {
    setPhone(event.target.value);
    isValid(validatePhoneNumber(event.target.value));
  };

  const validatePhoneNumber = (value) => {
    let isValidPhoneNumber = validator.isMobilePhone(value, "en-US");
    console.log(isValidPhoneNumber, value)
    return isValidPhoneNumber;
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="tel"
      className="w-full input-primary pl-8 focus:outline-none"
      onChange={setPhoneNum}
      value={phone}
      placeholder="123 456 7890"
    />
  );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(<Login />, domContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/validator@latest/validator.min.js"></script>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```